# Google Cloud Transfer changed Azure Storage source to beta

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

We have been using Google Cloud Transfer to move files from Azure Storage to Google Cloud Storage on production. The transfer stopped working recently (with error message permission denied) and no new transfer from this source is working. We noticed that Google again displays the tag "beta" next to the Microsoft Azure Storage Container option (despite the fact that according to their logs it went to General Acess in July 2020).

Does anybody else experience the same issue?
I was not able to find any official or unofficial information about this issue.

[image]

Comment: Could you give any more details on the error? Regarding the Beta notation, you are correct this is a feature that is generaly available, so this is likely a UI Bug, you can report this by opening a Bug Report in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0).

Comment: @RafaelLemos thank you for your confirmation and the tip to report UI bug. We have a daily transfer from Azure Blob Storage but since 2021-04-26 it fails with PERMISSION_DENIED (without further information). Additionally, the same happens with any newly created transfer, from different Blob Storages to different buckets. As it coincided with some further changes in transfers (and this beta tag), I was wondering if they have not change certificates or general availability of the services.

Comment: The issue was due to a temporary error in Google Transfers that has been corrected several days afterwards.